# lograr hacer menú con HTML y CSS

Tags: html5, css3

hola he estado intentando hacer una copia del menú de apple con html5 y css3. lo que pasa es que cuando he intentado solucionar un error con el tema del icono de la barra del buscador no me funciona, el objetivo que quiero llegar a alcanzar es:
que tenga un efecto hover blanco con el icono incluido en esta barra de buscador

lamento enserio si incumplo con las reglas las estudie un poco y creo que estoy bien, si tengo algún error me disculpo

código de HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>El KIOSCO</title>
                             <!------ estilos ------>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="E:\tienda\modelo\css\estilos.css">
                            <!------- logotipo ----->
  <link rel="icon" type="img" href="E:\tienda\modelo\img\logito.png">
                            <!------  ------>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css">
                            <!------  ------>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
                            <!------  ------>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/3b59cb85ac/UntitledProject/style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="menu-nav">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href=""><span class="icon-house"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="">Nosotros</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Producto</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contacto</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Registro</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="search_bar">
        <a href="#" class="icon-search"></a>
        <input type="text" id="bar">
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>


<!------------------ fin menu --------------->
</body>
```

este es el código HTML que tengo, no creo tener el error allí sino en el código CSS aquí se los dejo:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul, ol{
    list-style: none;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
}

.menu-nav {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #979797;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #555555;
    background: #8b8b8b;

    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">fondo: rgb (139,139,139);</font></font>
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">fondo: -moz-linear-gradient (top, rgba (139,139,139,1) 0%, rgba (106,106,106,1) 49%, rgba (94,94,94,1) 51%, rgba (113,113,113,1) 100% );</font></font>
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">fondo: -webkit-linear-gradient (top, rgba (139,139,139,1) 0%, rgba (106,106,106,1) 49%, rgba (94,94,94,1) 51%, rgba (113,113,113,1) 100% );</font></font>
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">fondo: gradiente lineal (hacia abajo, rgba (139,139,139,1) 0%, rgba (106,106,106,1) 49%, rgba (94,94,94,1) 51%, rgba (113,113,113,1) 100%);</font></font>
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">filtro: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient (startColorstr = '# 8b8b8b', endColorstr = '# 717171', GradientType = 0);</font></font>
}


.menu {
    width: 85%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    float: left;
}

.menu li {
    display: table-cell;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid #5c5c5c;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}

.menu li:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

.menu li:first-child:hover {
    border-left: none;
}

.menu li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0.5);
}

.menu li:hover {
    background: rgb(0,0,0.5);
    border-right: 1px solid transparent;
    border-left: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.menu li:active {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.search_bar {
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

.search_bar input {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #585858;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 22px;

    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0.7);

    background: #7E7E7E;
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">color de fondo: rgb (126,126,126);</font></font>
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">@incluye gradiente de filtro (# 7e7e7e, # 767676, vertical);</font></font>
    <font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">@incluir imagen de fondo (gradiente lineal (arriba, rgba (126,126,126,1) 0%, rgba (121,121,121,1) 50%, rgba (110,110,110,1) 52%, rgba (118,118,118,1) 100%);</font></font>
}




.search_bar input:focus {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.icon-house {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
}

.icon-search {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: ¿Osea que tanto el item del menú como el ícono de home se pongan blancos en hover?

Comment: que tenga un efecto hover con el ratón y que cuando se empieza a escribir en la barra de búsqueda el icono desaparezca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer la animacion en hover desde css, con los atributos que deseas que tenga

```
#icono:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

Para ocultar el icono, puedes detectar cuando hay una entrada en el input

```
document.getElementById("bar").addEventListener("keyup", function() {});
```

y ocultar el icono

```
document.getElementById("icono").style.display = "none";
```

```js
document.getElementById("bar").addEventListener("keyup", function() {

  if (document.getElementById("bar").value.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("icono").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("icono").style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style: none;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-nav {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #979797;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555555;
  background: #8b8b8b;
}

.menu {
  width: 85%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  float: left;
}

#icono:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/3b59cb85ac/UntitledProject/style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="menu-nav" style="width:100px">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href=""><span class="icon-house"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="">Nosotros</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Producto</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contacto</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Registro</a></li>
      </ul>
      <br>
      <div class="search_bar">
        <span href="#" class="icon-search" id="icono"></span>
        <input type="text" id="bar">
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>


</body>
```